# INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012:

The query is:

```
create table t11 (pid int not null, emp varchar(10))
create table t12 (id bigint, fn varchar(100))

create view tesr
as
   select 
       a.pid, b.fn 
   from 
       t11 a 
   join 
       t12 b on a.pid = b.id

create trigger tesr_trig on dbo.tesr
instead of insert
as 
begin
    insert into t11  
       select i.pid, i.emp 
       from inserted i

    insert into t12  
       select i.id, i.fn 
       from inserted i
end
```

I get the following error while executing:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tesr_trig, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'emp'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tesr_trig, Line 6
>   Invalid column name 'id'.

What is mistake I am making?

Comment: There is no column `id` or `emp` in the projection of your view

Answer (score 4):

You are creating the trigger on the view, so the `inserted` pseudotable will contain the view's columns, and neither `emp` or `id` are present.

You'll need to change your view to :

```
alter view tesr
as
    select a.pid, b.fn, a.emp from t11 a join t12 b on a.pid=b.id
```

And your trigger needs to be cognaisant of the join in the view between `a.pid and b.id`, so the view's `pid` value needs to be inserted into both tables.

```
ALTER trigger tesr_trig on dbo.tesr
instead of insert
as 
begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  insert into t11(pid, emp)
    select i.pid,i.emp from inserted i
  insert into t12(id, fn)
    select i.pid,i.fn from inserted i
end
```

Then the view insert:

```
INSERT INTO tesr(pid, fn, emp) VALUES (1, 'fn', 'emp')
```

Will insert into the two underlying tables of the view.

Answer (score 1):

Your view doesn't have the columns you're using in the trigger.
Even more: there are only two columns in the view and you use three in the trigger.